# How to specify number of digits when writing a table?

Tags: r, xlsx

I have a matrix with 12 rows and 12 columns

```
    AirAnalysis2019 <- matrix(c(...), nrow = 12, ncol = 12, byrow = TRUE,
                       dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"),  
                                       c(...)))
```

Now, I'm trying to write an Excel file with this using the xlsx package:

```
    write.xlsx2(AirAnalysis2019, file="xxx.xlsx", sheetName="AirAnalysis2019", 
    col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, append=FALSE, showNA = FALSE)
```

Is it possible to tell the software that I wish to get the values of the columns 1, 5 and 9 in a "scientific" format while all the other values appear with 2 digits only ?
Also, is it possible with this package to color specifically the name of the rows ?

Thank for you help

Comment: I think you need to adjust the matrix before writing it to a `xlsx` file. You can use `AirAnalysis2019[, c(1,5,9)] <- sprintf("%e", AirAnalysis2019[, c(1,5,9)])` to change values of the columns 1, 5 and 9 to the scientific format.